# HashMap in Java programming

Tags: java, hashmap, copy

How do I copy a Map of string to Vector to another map.
I am doing this

```
Map<String,Vector<allocated>>map_to_input_copy=new HashMap<String,Vector<allocated>>();
Map<String,Vector<allocated>>map_to_output_copy=new HashMap<String,Vector<allocated>>();
map_to_input_copy.putAll(map_to_inputs);
map_to_output_copy.putAll(map_to_outputs);
```

But after modification in map_to_input_copy map_to_inputs is also getting effected.
For checking I am printing

```
System.out.println("before"+map_to_inputs.get("5c").get(1).output);
```

And

```
System.out.println("after"+map_to_inputs.get("5c").get(1).output);
```

Here output is attribute in allocated class
But both are different.Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the vector objects to the new map, so in the new map there are the identical vector objects, with the same content. If you modify the content of the vector object it shows up in both maps, because it is the same.

What you need to do is a so called deep copy, that means iterate over the entries and create a copy of the vector objects also.

BTW: Use of the Vector class is heavily discouraged. ArrayList is the modern and faster replacement.